# Linked Lists Class

Tags: c++, linked-list

Okay I know this is a ridiculously easy question, but for some reason I cannot get a linked list to work.  It may just be because I am really tired, because I've done them a million times before.  Boiled my program down to the simplest possible implementation, still not working.

Very basic implementation, just make a LL of integers, something I have done a million times before but for whatever reason it's never progressing past head.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ll.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    list ll;
    int i =0;


    while(i == 0)
    {
    cout << "Enter a value to add to the LL ";
    cin >> x;

    ll.add(x);
    ll.display();
    }

return 0;
}
```

**ll.h**

```
struct node
{
    int val;
    node * next;
};

class list
{
    public:
    list();

    void add(int);
    void display();
    node * head;
};
```

**ll.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ll.h"
using namespace std;

list::list()
{
    head = NULL;
}

void list::add(int x)
{
    if(!head)
    {
        cout << "First  " << endl;
        head = new node;
        head->val = x;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node * current = head;
        while (current)
            current = current->next;

        current = new node;
        current->val = x;
        current->next = NULL;

    }
}

void list::display()
{
    node * current = head;

    while(current)
    {
        cout << current->val << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: The while loop in your main won't work because the value of `i` will never change. `while ( i == 0 )` will never be false.

Comment: What is not working? Describe the undesired behavior you are getting

Comment: Of course, in real code you should be using `std::list<int>` (or `std::forward_list<int>` if you have a C++11 compiler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to append to the list. In this case, you loop condition shouldn't be

```
while (current)
```

but

```
while (current->next)
```

making sure is initially non-NULL (which you do with your check for the `head).

Actually, the logic for setting up the new node is also not quite right. You probably want to have the second branch of `add()` look something like this:

```
while (current->next) {
    current = current->next;
}
current->next = new node(x);
```

... with a suitable constructor of `node`:

```
node::node(int x): val(x), next() {}
```

Comment: And do `current->next = new Node` when you are done instead of instantly overriding `current` with a new value

Comment: I agree, it is just an addition to finalizing the answer. I totally agree and have upvoted the answer.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out right after I posted the question.  That's what I get for trying to code at 4 am.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Dietmar's answer, you have an improper while loop:

```
while ( i == 0 ) {
     ...
}
```

In the body of the for loop, `i` is never changed, causing it to loop indefinitely. I'm not entirely sure what you want to use `i` for though.

Comment: It is just an infinite loop, adding elements as long as you keep typing ;)